# ASP.NET master page datepicker in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Datepicker Code in Master Page in asp.net as below

```
<link  href="~/AppThemes/js/datepicker/datepicker.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/AppThemes/js/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            var dp = $(".datePicker1");
            var a = dp.datepicker({ dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And My DatePicker Html Code is on content6 page is below

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>License Expiry Date</label>
   <div class="input-group date" >
     <span class="input-group-addon add-on entypo-calendar datePicker1"></span>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtDlExpDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datePicker1" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"> </asp:TextBox>
   </div>
</div>
```

when i click on textbox the jquery is not working. I import Jquery and CSS file on master page and i use that in content page what is the problem please help me.

Comment: `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);` here you called `EndRequestHandler` function without argument, while `EndRequestHandler` function take two argument `(sender, args)`.Please check browser console to see errors

Comment: To @Alive to Die, there is no error  on console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `datePicker1` class from span just use,

```
<div class="input-group date" >
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on entypo-calendar"></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDlExpDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control datePicker1" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"> </asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Inspect the input element, and check it has `datePicker1` class added in it. Also check if there are any errors shown in broswer's console

Comment: To @Rohan Kumar I check it class is add and no error to console same code working on another machine

Comment: Check all required JS and CSS are included in your page and there are no multiple versions of any JS library (specially Jquery). Also your bootstrap 
 library must be included after Jquery. And try to clear browser's cache or try your code in Private window.

Comment: Yes, sir, i got the answer the problem behind that script file for jquery is not updated on content placeholder when writing code on content placeholder it works.....